# In Django view, how can I change the value of the class member?

Tags: python, django, webserver

I want to increase candidate's *earn* value if he got vote. So I write this part in the *result_view*, but it doesn't work.

Here are my views.

---

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from election.models import *

# /candidate/ view
def candidate_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        c = Candidate.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('candidate.html', {'candidates': c})

# /candidate/result/ view
def result_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = Candidate.objects.all()
        ec = Candidate.objects.filter(num=request.POST.get('choice'))

        ec[0].earn += 1
        ec[0].name = 'semi kwon'
        ec[0].save()

        #return render_to_response('result.html', {'candidates': ec})
        return render_to_response('result.html', {'candidates': c})
```

---

And here's my model.

---

```
from django.db import models


class Candidate(models.Model):

    num = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.TextField()
    major = models.TextField()
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    earn = models.IntegerField(default = 0, blank=True, editable=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%d : %s"%(self.num, self.name,)
```

---

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcom to stackoverflow! I edited the indendation of your code example for better readability. Please pay attention that a code block should start with an indendation of 4 spaces. It would be also of use if you can provide a snippet of your template.

Comment: Do you also have a form (something like ``CandidateForm(ModelForm)``)? In your ``result_view`` you're processing the user input that should be done in a form, but you didn't provide the required code for that.

Comment: @cezar Thank you for your warm welcome :>!! I'll keep in mind that from now on.

Comment: @cezar I get user input in the html page by the radio button! I've just solve this problem with everyone's help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the database after updating your candidate?

Since you're getting candidates (c) before you update the candidate(ec), you might have updated the candidate but passed an old set to the template.

It would be better to use a form, but to keep your logic, try this:

```
def result_view(request):
    # csrf update etc
    # your request.method GET here
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # dictionary with vars that will be passed to the view
        params = {}

        # check if there is a candidate with this num
        # before you do anything with it
        # you could do a try/except instead
        if Candidate.objects.filter(num=request.POST.get('choice')).count():
            # Getting candidate
            candidate = Candidate.objects.get(num=request.POST.get('choice'))
            # Updating candidate
            candidate.earn += 1
            # I don't know what this is, but let's keep it
            candidate.name = 'semi known'
            # Saving candidate
            candidate.save() 

        else:
            # returning error, candidate not found
            params['error'] = "No candidate with this num"

         # updating candidates list
         params['candidates'] = Candidate.objects.all()

         # rendering view
         return render_to_response('result.html', params)
```

Comment: actually, semi kwon is my name :D...kkk. I've just forgot to delete that.

Comment: Ok, you can accept this answer and close this question ;-)

Comment: How can I accept your answer..? As it's the first time I open my question here, so I don't know how to accept ㅠ_ㅠ..

Comment: There's an "accept" link on the left side of the answers, under the arrows up or down. You just have to click the one you want to mark

Comment: I think you just clicked the star on your question. That makes it a favourite. You want to click on the symbol ( √ ) on the left of the answer you select as correct, under the arrows, otherwise this will stay open...

Comment: It means that you found a solution for your problem, the best answer, so in case someone has the same problem, it will be easy to find the solution.